# WSO2 API Manager cluster Key Manager

Tags: wso2, wso2-api-manager

I am setting up the API Manager in a cluster and have one version of the store and one version of the publisher which are clustered so they update each other on change. I also have the gateway setup up in a master and worker cluster. All of this I found out how to do on the wso2 site. The issue is I want to cluster the key manager as well for higher load but I can't find any documentation on how to cluster the key manager specifically. I assume it's not just a case of running more than one behind a load balancer as they need to know when the tokens etc have changed?

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Are you using WSO2 API Manager as Key manager?

Comment: Yes I am using WSO2 API Manager and not Identity server

Answer (score -3):

Please follow this [documentation](https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER420/Clustering+API+Manager#ClusteringAPIManager-CreateaclusterofGatewaycomponents) on API Manager clustering. Please follow Configuring the connections among the components -> Key Manager section and Configuring component features section accordingly. This [blog](http://ushanib.blogspot.com/2015/05/simple-explaination-for-url.html) post explains when IS is used as Key Manager. But the explanation might be helpful to you to understand when using several urls.

Comment: Peter made it clear that he had used WSO2 documentation to get to this point. There is no specific section in their documentation that describes how to configure a clustered Key Manager.